# Arrange text file with one word per line

Tags: text-processing

I have text file with a lot of text in it, and I would like to sort every word one below other how can I do that. For ex.

```
cat PDF | less
word one, word two. Word three ?
```

I need them to be

```
word
one
word
two
Word
three
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't really what I would call sorting.

You could either squeeze and transliterate all non-alphabetic sequences into newlines

```
tr -sc '[:alpha:]' '[\n*]' < PDF
```

or (at least with GNU grep) match and output sequences of *word* characters (alpha, decimal digits and underscore), one per line using the `-o` option

```
grep -o '\w*' PDF
```